# SQL, C# - Can't convert int32 to string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, type-conversion

Alright, so I have the following SQL query:

```
 query.CommandText = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, Age FROM Characters WHERE LastName LIKE   '"+name+"' ORDER BY Age";
```

And this loop that stores the result in the string "output"

```
while (reader.Read()) {
    output = output + reader.GetString(0) + reader.GetString(1) + reader.GetString(2).ToString();
}
```

However, for the third attribute `age`, which is an int, I get an error

> could not convert System.Int32 to type System.String

As you see, I've already tried to solve this by using the `int.ToString()` function but I still get the same error. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `reader.GetString(2).ToString()` is pointless ;)

Comment: Please look up "SQL Injection" in your search engine of choice.

Comment: If you read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it states that no conversion is performed, so the data retrieved must already be a `string`, `Int32`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

agree with Tim but something like

```
reader[2].ToString();
```

may be more generic and less buggy if you change your select order.

following Tim Comment:

```
reader["Age"].ToString();
```

Comment: If you change the select it is better to   get an exception at `GetInt32` instead of an incorrect result.

Comment: @TimSchmelter true also

Answer (score 6):

`reader.GetString(2).ToString()` is pointless, it either is already a string or you use the wrong method. Since you've mentioned that it's an `int` use `reader.GetInt32`:

```
string firstName = reader.GetString(0);
string larstName = reader.GetString(1);
int age = reader.GetInt32(2);
output = output + string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", firstName, lastName, age);
```

If the column `Age` is nullable you need to use `IsDBNull` first, you could also use an `int?` then:

```
int? age = null;
if(!reader.IsDBNull(2))
    age = reader.GetInt32(2);
```

If you want to access a field by it's name rather than via index, use `GetOrdinal`:

```
int ageIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("Age");
int? age = null;
if(!reader.IsDBNull(ageIndex))
    age = reader.GetInt32(ageIndex);
```

---

As an important aside, you're open for sql-injection here:

```
query.CommandText = @"SELECT FirstName, LastName, Age 
                      FROM Characters 
                      WHERE LastName LIKE '" + name + "' ORDER BY Age";
```

because you're concatenating the sql query. Instead use sql-parameters:

```
query.CommandText = @"SELECT FirstName, LastName, Age 
                      FROM Characters 
                      WHERE LastName LIKE '%' + @LastName + '%' 
                      ORDER BY Age";
query.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = name;
```

(if you don't want to find also substrings you don't need to use `LIKE`, then you can use `=`)

Comment: Right, that makes sense! Never used the reader before so I didn't research which methods it has